# When I add in <!DOCTYPE html>, div measurements do not work

Tags: css, html, doctype

I am currently working on a website, and made this div:

```
#container #content .imagewindow {
width: 560;
height: 380;
background-color: #1E1640;

}
```

On adding in the doctype html; the browser seems to ignore my commands and simply resizes the div to the full allocated space. The page is http://www.cantabilechoir.ca/gallery.html#n ; for now I have left it without the doctype html.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 560 feet? Inches? Pixels? You need units.

Comment: @Blender hehe we dont have feets yet... also css lacks miles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify which units you will be using to size it. I assume you want to use pixels so change the numbers to 560px and 380px.

Answer (score 2):

#### Please add "px" in you css values.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi! Just use** width and height attributes values in `px,em or %;` If you use HTML5 so include this line of HTML code
`<!DOCTYPE html>` It tells the browser that the this html page is HTML5 and browser will render HTML5 rules.
One thing at last which is not requirement by you but it is required to know the users.Just drag and drop the image in the new tab browser or save the image in your local drive and open the image to visible exactly

[image]